# Problem with fglrx package

Tags: server, 10.04

guys,
I have a big problem ...
Whatever I want to do (at first I wanted reinstall php5), `install, remove, upgrade, ...` nothing works.

I got some error, I'm really stuck ... Here is some, when I try to upgrade:

```
root@preprod:/var/lib/mysql# aptitude safe-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
open: 33; closed: 4991; defer: 9204; conflict: 2                                                                                                 oThe following packages have unmet dependencies:
  fglrx: Depends: xserver-xorg-core but it is not installable
         Depends: dkms but it is not installable
```

Then I tried to install xserver-xorg-core:

```
root@preprod:/var/lib/mysql# apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  cpp-4.4 g++-4.4 gcc-4.4 gcc-4.4-base gcc-4.6-base ifupdown initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initscripts keyboard-configuration lib32gcc1
  libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libc6-i386 libdrm-nouveau1a libffi6 libgcc1 libgfortran3 libgl1-mesa-dri libgmp10 libgomp1 libllvm3.0
  libmpfr4 libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libplymouth2 libquadmath0 libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.4-dev libtinfo5 locales mountall plymouth
  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text upstart
Suggested packages:
  gcc-4.4-locales g++-4.4-multilib gcc-4.4-doc libstdc++6-4.4-dbg gcc-4.4-multilib libmudflap0-4.4-dev libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libmudflap0-dbg
  libcloog-ppl0 libppl-c2 libppl7 rdnssd glibc-doc libglide3 libstdc++6-4.4-doc graphviz xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fglrx libdrm-nouveau1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.6-base initramfs-tools keyboard-configuration libdrm-nouveau1a libffi6 libgmp10 libllvm3.0 libnih-dbus1 libquadmath0 libtinfo5 mountall
  plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text upstart xserver-xorg-core
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-4.4 g++-4.4 gcc-4.4 gcc-4.4-base ifupdown initramfs-tools-bin initscripts lib32gcc1 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libc6-i386
  libgcc1 libgfortran3 libgl1-mesa-dri libgomp1 libmpfr4 libnih1 libplymouth2 libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.4-dev locales
23 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 2 to remove and 283 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/45.3MB of archives.
After this operation, 90.6MB disk space will be freed.
```

But i got this error:
    E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'plymouth'.Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)

There are errors anywhere ...
I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 TLS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the package directly with apt-get? Your question is tagged with the server tag, so on a server the fglrx package is normally not needed:

```
apt-get remove fglrx
```

Alternativily you can try the fix-broken option of apt-get:

```
apt-get install -f
```